# Difference between EventHub and Topic in Azure

Tags: azure, publish-subscribe, azureservicebus

I am building an application that needs to be able to create events, publish them, and have multiple consumers. The tutorials I have found so far suggest that Azure Topics are the right thing to use for this (multiple publishers and multiple subscribers), but I noticed an option in my Azure portal for EventHub and it seems like a highly scalable solution that may be a newer implementation of Pub/Sub for Azure. I have been searching for documentation comparing the two and haven't really found anything. Can someone explain why I would choose one of these solutions over the other.

The scenario I have is many clients in a Multi-Tenant application may create events at any time, those events need to be published to "n" subscribers for consumption. The subscribers need to be able to change without any change to the application (i.e. subscribers should be able to subscribe themselves to events without modifying publisher code).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event Hubs have below advantage as compared with Azure ServiceBus:

1. Its client-side cursor: Developers can use a client-side pointer, or
   offset, to retrieve messages from a specific point in the event
   stream
2. Partitioned consumer support: Throughput Unit and inbound messages
   can be targeted at a specific partition through a user-defined
   partition key value.
3. Significant time-based retention options